# Oracle SQL: SELECT date FROM outcome_o Code: (936) ORA-00936: missing expression

Tags: oracle

When I do this query:

```
SELECT date FROM income_o;
```

I have this error:

> Error in query. Code: (936) ORA-00936: missing expression

Here is [database schema](http://www.sql-ex.ru/help/select13.php#db_2)

I do not really know what to do or what is missing :(

And how should I rewrite it for this form `income_o.date` to work?

Comment: Can you try `SELECT [date] FROM Income_o;`

Comment: I believe the square brackets are the Microsoft Access equivalent of the double-quotes in Oracle - they are not part of the column name, they just escape the name. (MS Access or who knows what other DB.)

Comment: Any table that uses [date] as a column name should have the database designer lined up against a wall and beaten to death with boiled cauliflower.

Answer (score 1):

Below query will work.

```
 SELECT t."date" FROM tableName t;
```

Answer (score 0):

It is unfortunate that your tables contain a column "date" - that is a reserved word in Oracle, used to input date literals. The date literal is what is missing and throws the error.

In fact that is not YOUR error; what you want is the column named date. Put it in double-quotes, like so:

```
SELECT "date" FROM income_o;
```

Comment: What if I want to use it in this form `income_o.date`? how should I rewrite it?